# Android LinearLayout dynamic text struggle

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to achieve displaying 3 items next to each other

[ICON-and-text-inside] [Dynamic Text] [Dynamic List with dynamic width]

The following is my source

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                >

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:src="@drawable/bullet_bg_36px"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="10."
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="14dp"/>
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LongText1 - LongText2 - LongText3 - LongText4"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                />
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="??? reps"

                  android:textColor="#c2df00"
                  android:background="#000000"
                  android:paddingEnd="2dp"
                  android:paddingStart="2dp"
                  android:singleLine="true"
                  android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="with ??? lbs"

                android:textColor="#c2df00"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:paddingEnd="2dp"
                android:paddingStart="2dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Which currently behaves like the following screenshot:

[image]

I want the middle [dynamic text] to wrap ONLY (**to multiple lines if necessary**), while the first (icon+textinside) and last (list) to display fully and properly.

Also if the middle text is not wide enough, then I want the list to be displayed right after it (like shown in Scenario #1).

Comment: First try using layout_weight in the LinearLayout. Weight determines how much of the screen each view gets. If that doesnt work, try switching over to a Relative Layout, it allows you to position things relative to each other, that should be easiest

Comment: Dear drees: My initial approach was RelativeLayout which produced similar result. My experiment with the layout_weight didn't bring any success, yet :(

Answer (score 1):

Do something like that. My example uses 3 textviews, just replace it with your controls:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    tools:context=".SearchResultActivity" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="aaa"/>

     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text3"
        android:text="bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="ccc"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This does not satisfy my scenario-#1 requirements.